# Partial function object has no attribute "__code__"

Tags: python, python-3.x, partial, functools

I am writing a small application that takes users' input to give them a set of optimal parameters to use. (Each of these sets are ranked and the user can select whichever one they want to use)

To be able to do this, I select one function from an array of choices(depending on the context), partially fill the function using `functools.partial` then return the partial object to another module which in turn calls a C++ library (`dlib`) which has a python interface.

Up until today, I wasn't using `functools.partial` to fill the function and faced no issues. But to make the code less repetitive and easier to understand, I added that in. After adding that part, I get the following error :

> AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__code__'

I read a few posts and realized that this is an issue with `partial` objects as they often lack attributes like `__name__`, `__module__` etc but I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

PS: I am using python 3.7

**EDIT**

I am adding a small code that reproduces the error

```
from functools import partial
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from dlib import find_max_global

def objective_calculator(*args, X, y):
    args = args[0]
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.set_params(**{'class_weight': args[0], 'max_iter':args[1]})
    model.fit(train['data'], train['target'])
    predictions = model.predict(X)
    return accuracy_score(y, predictions)

train = load_breast_cancer()
obj_calc = partial(objective_calculator, X=train['data'], y=train['target'])
lower_bounds = [0.1, 10] # class_weight, max_iter
upper_bounds = [0.5, 200] # class_weight, max_iter
is_integer_variable = [False, True]

find_max_global(f=obj_calc,
                bound1=lower_bounds,
                bound2=upper_bounds,
                num_function_calls=2,
                is_integer_variable=is_integer_variable,
                solver_epsilon=1,)
```

Running the above code results in the following error

> AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__code__'

Is it advisable to manually add the `__code__` attribute to the partial object?

Comment: show code which gives this error.

Comment: @furas, the code is part of a larger code base. I need some time to produce an mvc code.

Comment: @furas, I have added a small code in the edit section. Please take a look

Comment: @furas, maybe you could help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882865/how-to-add-code-attribute-to-a-function

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__code__'
```

for solving this error we can use

## wraps

`functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` to update attributes, 
which defaults to ('**module**', '**name**', '**doc**')
 in python 2.7.6
or,

we can update only present attributes...

````
import functools

import itertools

def wraps_safely(obj, attr_names=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS):
return wraps(obj, assigned=itertools.ifilter(functools.partial(hasattr, obj), attr_names))

`>>> def foo():
`... `   ` """ Ubiquitous foo function ...."""`
... 

>>> functools.wraps(partial(foo))(foo)()

`Traceback (most recent call last):



File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>



 File ```"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", ``line 33, in update_wrapper`

setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))

AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'

>>> wraps_safely(partial(foo))(foo)()

>>> `
````

`

## just filter out all those attribute which aren't present.

## second approach would be:-

*strictly deal with partial objects only.

fold wraps with `singledispatch` and it creates wrapped partial object and its attribute would be taken from the function "fun" attribute.

import functools

```
  def wraps_partial(wrapper, *args, **kwargs):
`    """ Creates a callable object whose attributes will be set from the partials nested func attribute ..."""

 ` ` ` wrapper = wrapper.func``



 while isinstance(wrapper, functools.partial):


 wrapper = wrapper.func


 return functools.wraps(wrapper, *args, **kwargs)

# after returning functools.wraps

def foo():
""" Foo function.
:return: None """


 pass

>>> wraps_partial(partial(partial(foo)))(lambda : None).__doc__

' Foo Function, returns None '

>>> wraps_partial(partial(partial(foo)))(lambda : None).__name__

'foo'

>>> wraps_partial(partial(partial(foo)))(lambda : None)()

>>> pfoo = partial(partial(foo))



 >>> @wraps_partial(pfoo)



 ... def not_foo():


 ... 




 """ Not Foo function ... """


    ... 

 >>> not_foo.__doc__



 ' Foo Function, returns None '

>>> not_foo.__name__

'foo'



 >>>
```

## now we can get the original functions docs.

## python(CPython) 3.

from functools import wraps, partial, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS

try:

```
 wraps(partial(wraps))(wraps)



 except AttributeError:



  @wraps(wraps)


 def wraps(obj, attr_names=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, wraps=wraps):


 return wraps(obj, assigned=(name for name in attr_names if hasattr(obj, name)))
```

*we define a new wraps function only if we fail to wrap a partial,*
*use the original wraps to copy the docs*

also,

In (Python 3.5) we have  a reference to the original function, and it  is maintained in the partial. You can access it as `.func:`

from `functools`import partial

```
 def a(b):
print(b)


In[20]:  c=partial(a,5)


In[21]:  c.func.__module__

Out[21]: '__main__'

In[22]:  c.func.__name__

Out[22]: 'a'
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, would you like to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

I would not dare adding a `__code__` attribute to a `partial` object. The `__code__` attribute allows a low level access to the *compiled* Python code. It is normally never used in common scripts and is probably used here to interface it with the underlying C++ library.

The bullet proof way is to define a new function. In Python `def` is an executable statement, and it is possible to iterately redefine a function:

```
def objective_calculator(*args, X, y):
    ...

for X, y in ...:
    def obj_calc(*args):
        return objective_calculator(*args, X, y)
    ...
    find_max_global(f=obj_calc, ...)
```

`obj_calc` is now a true Python function and it will have its own `__code__` attribute.

---

If the `dlib` library supports it, it could be possible to use a `lambda`:

```
find_max_global(f=lambda *args: objective_calculator(*args, X, y), ...)
```

A lambda is almost a true function and has indeed a `__code__` attribute, but it is defined as a separate object class in Python, so depending on the dlib library requirements (I could not find any reference on it) it could work or not.